# Adding CR-LF pair to output of VBA Macro in Access

Tags: email, ms-access, automation

I expected to find answers to this on the web but have been unlucky so far.

I am producing an Access macro to send a query as an excel file by email. I am using emailDatabaseObject.

This offers me several fields all of which I have completed but the Message Text Field doesn't allow me a new line. I have tried enter, "..." & vbCrLf & "...", \vbCrLf, alt+10 alt+13, and other things none of which work.

**At the moment I have:**

> *Shane.  \n \r ­­­­  Please find the latest list attached.    Regards ...*

**Would like to have:**

> *Shane.*
>
> *Please find the latest list attached.*
>
> *Regards ...*

Does anyone know how to get a newline in a field like this? Please let me know if you can, thanks.

Scriptham

Comment: Thanks for your answers, unfortunately neither work. I am sure that they would in VBA but they don't in the macro. I have tried using standard email mark-up The option to use a template file in the macro doesn't work. If it did I could probably select html format and then it becomes easy as you have pointed out. I have decided to edit the email which allows me to add a signature.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Chr(10)`?

```
"Shane." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
"Please find the latest list attached." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
"Regards ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If  Zaider's trick `char(13)` or `char(10)` doesn't work, I guess your output format is **HTML**, then you should use `<br>` :

```
Shane. <br> <br> ­­­­ Please find the latest list attached. <br><br>Regards ..
```

Which renders :

> Shane. 
>  
>  ­­­­ Please find the latest list attached. 
>   
> Regards ..

Comment: In Outlook, an email object of type `ObjectMailItem` has a `BodyFormat` attribute which can be `olFormatPlain`, `olFormatRichText`, `olFormatHTML`, or `olFormatUnspecified`.